# Installation of Whitebox plugin in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18, whitebox-gat

I want to install the plugin Whitebox (https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html) into QGIS 2.18 but it is not listed in the Plugin Repository. I have the zip file. Is it possible?

I have given up on QGIS 3.xx for my current tasks for the time (where I can install the plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add plugins to QGIS from .zip files. Navigate to your QGIS user profile; this may be a hidden folder, on mac it is under Macintosh HDD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸USERNAME ▸ ⁨.qgis2⁩ ▸ ⁨python⁩⁩ ▸ ⁨plugins and paste the unzipped folder into here. A restart of QGIS is then usually required but it should show up in your list of installed plugins.

Unfortunately in this case the plugin is designed for QGIS 3.x so it comes up as an invalid plugin on QGIS 2.18:

[image: Invalid plugin dialogue]

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\.qgis2\python\plugins on Windows 10.